# Offset Wall Color From Reflected Image

Tags: image-processing, color, projection

I have a movie projector which is projecting an image on a brown wall. The projector allows me to adjust 6 values. Red brightness, Green brightness, Blue brightness. Red contrast, Green contrast, Blue contrast.

Is it possible to "cancel out" the color of the brown wall by adjusting the RGB values of the projector? By cancel out, I mean so that the end result of the projected image is equivalent, as if the wall was a more neutral gray or white.

If this is possible, is there a way to do it without an expensive colorimeter? Maybe with some image processing from a phone camera?

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on what colors the wall reflects?  If it's painted with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantablack you won't have much luck making it reflect white.

Comment: Ha hopefully not that intense. But a darker color should still work (like a gray).

Comment: But you get the idea?  If the wall is white, it reflects all colors, so illuminating it with only red will make it red.  If the wall only reflects green, then it's not possible to make it red.  The red will just be absorbed and it will stay black.  In reality probably all walls reflect *some* of each color?  But it depends.

Comment: If the wall reflects 'half' green, what would happen if you reduce the projector's green RGB value by half?

Comment: It would be darker green?